# listen elements rendering after DOM initially loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

Is there anyway to listen for elements adding themselves to the DOM after load? Currently I have a bunch of tables using DataTables and I have a bunch of other elements that I would like to manipulate when and if the type of element I am looking for is found to have "appeared" on the page. Seeing as what I am attempting to do only works on elements currently on the page when loaded but not after they load such is the case with many elements currently in play.

Ultimately I am currently looking for a means of avoiding going back through the entire code base just to make something happen only if something is found on the page, but after its loaded.

Comment: There is no cross-browser way of handling this because the original way (DOMMutationEvents) was very inefficient. There are now Observers for this, however that also is not cross-browser yet. If these elements are all being added by jQuery methods, you can use the livequery plugin to do this, which monkeypatches all of the dom manipulation methods to catch when new elements are added using jQuery methods.

Comment: Usually when you have to ask this question, it means you need to rethink your logic and reorganize it in such a way that you are able to run code after said elements are added on a case-by-case basis rather than trying to do a global listener listening for any element to be added to the DOM. For example, an ajax request's success callback. An alternative (as pointed out by zzzzBov) is delegated events, but that of course only works for events.

Comment: Unfortunately the code base is to well established and out in production. For the time being I am stuck working with that I have. Until my company allows me the time to rebuild everything from the ground up on the front end

Answer (score 2):

There's no "element added to dom" sort of event that's cross-browser compatible, and the ones that exist for specific browsers are generally discouraged as they tend to cause more issues than they solve.

Usually the issue with elements not existing in the DOM is that they miss event-binding. jQuery has awesome event-delegation that can be used to bind events to a container so that when an event bubbles up to the container, the callback is fired in the context of the element that received the event.

For example, you could bind events using:

```
$('a').click(doStuff);
```

but that would not work for any new links, instead you could use something like:

```
$('#some-container').on('click', 'a', doStuff);
```

which would intercept all click events on all links in the `#some-container` element, regardless of when they were added to the page.